# cppvsdbg from Visual Studio Code not jumping into DLL source file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-code

After having regained an interest in C++ recently, I've been fiddling around a bit with it and as I thought I might need to use a DLL some day, I wanted to know how to build and use one by myself in the first place.

As I'm using Visual Studio Code, I can't (and actually don't want to) use the wizardry of the proprietary Visual Studio versions that are doing a lot of magic in the background. My goal in this was to specifically be able to do it manually using MSVC so as to better understand the processes and commands behind it.

So as a first step, I followed the offical [MSDN tutorial on creating and using own DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019), translating the steps on there into MSVC tool commands and to my own surprise, it all went well and now I'm having my DLL lying around and getting used by my sample application.

The next step for me was then to be able to debug that DLL with the debugger jumping right into the source file, but that's where I'm struggling a bit. I am linking the DLL with /DEBUG to create a PDB and also am compiling the consumer application with /Zi to have debugging symbols enabled in there, too.

Debugging the consumer source works as expected, but when trying to jump *into* a function exported by the DLL, the debugger simply steps over.

These are the commands I am running / steps I am taking (full path up to the workspace replaced with `${ws}` to have the lines shorter here):

Compile the library:

```
cl.exe /EHsc /c /DMATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS /Fo: ${ws}\obj\ ${ws}\src\MathLibrary.cpp
```

Link it as DLL with debug symbols:

```
link.exe /DLL /DEBUG /OUT:${ws}\out\MathLibrary.dll ${ws}\obj\MathLibrary.obj
```

Compile the DLL consumer with debugging symbols

```
cl.exe /EHsc /Zi /Fo: ${ws}\obj\ /Fe: ${ws}\bin\math_d.exe ${ws}\src\MathClient.cpp ${ws}\out\MathLibrary.lib
```

Then I copy the `MathLibrary.dll` and the `MathLibrary.pdb` from `out\` to `bin\` (for the executable to be able to load it) and then run it with the results described above. The debug console in VSCode reads

```
Loaded '${ws}\bin\MathLibrary.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

so part of it seems to work, but I'm not sure on what to try next.

I assume I am either missing something in the linking of the DLL or the compilation of the consumer, but I don't know what exactly it is. I have read that the linker requires both, the DLL and its PDB to be available when linking the executable consuming the DLL, but I'm not quite sure what exactly this means.

Do I need to compile and link the executable in separate steps, passing the DDL's PDB to the linker command for it to "incorporate" it into the executable's PDB?
Or am I making false assumptions here and "jumping into the source of a DLL" is simply not possible? If so, how exactly would I debug a DLL's code, especially if it's my own?

Comment: You should build dll with `/Zi`, it is also a good idea to use `/DEBUG:FULL`

Comment: @VTT Nice, thanks a lot! Building the DLL with `/Zi` did the trick. If you could add it as an answer, I can mark it as the answer to the question. Could you also explain on how using `/Zi` while compiling and `/DEBUG` while linking differ? I've noticed that when compiling with `/Zi`, I can actually omit the `/DEBUG` in the linking, but don't quite get why. I thought `/Zi` would only take effect when I let the compiler invoke the linker, but not when doing it separately.

Comment: @VTT I think I've figured it out. `/Zi` creates the PDB for the .obj file, whereas `/DEBUG:FULL` uses that PDB to create the "real" PDB for the actual DLL, right? Also I'm taking back that I'm able to omit `/DEBUG:FULL`, I actually need to have both, `/Zi` and `/DEBUG:FULL`.